# Is mmap() faster than read() for perf_event_open

Tags: c, mmap, perf, intel-pmu

I am looking to monitor a number of events (hardware, software, and hardware cache) in my application. As with most applications that do profiling, performance is key. In an ideal world I would be able to read the CPU PMU events directly for CPU Cycle Count and others using mrs instructions. But since the kernel disables PMU access from EL0 by default, I am stuck using perf with my application.

As it stands, my `read_values()` function below uses [read()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) to read the results. I've been looking into ways to speed up the retrieval of these perf event values and came across this [PMU HW Counter access](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/arch/arm64/perf.html#perf-userspace-pmu-hardware-counter-access) document.

My question then is two fold:

1. Is using [mmap()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) instead of read() to retrieve the values from the fd a performance improvement? If so, how would I accomplish this?
2. Is there a way to use a mrs instructor to retrieve the PMU registers directly? From the [PMU HW Counter access](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/arch/arm64/perf.html#perf-userspace-pmu-hardware-counter-access) link above, it states this should be possible. Though I am having trouble finding examples that explain how to do this.

```
struct read_format {
  uint64_t nr;          /* The number of events */
  struct {
    uint64_t value;     /* The value of the event */
    uint64_t id;        /* if PERF_FORMAT_ID */
  } values[nr];
};

int main() {
  struct perf_event_attr attr1;
  attr1.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
  attr1.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
  attr1.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  int main_fd = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &attr1, 0, -1, -1, 0);
  uint64_t id1;
  ioctl(main_fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id1);
  ioctl(main_fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
  ioctl(main_fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

  struct perf_event_attr attr2;
  attr2.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
  attr2.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_REFERENCES;
  attr2.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  int fd2 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &attr2, 0, -1, main_fd, 0);
  uint64_t id2;
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id2);
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

  // read_values and log "START"

  // action

  // read_values and log "END"

  return 0;
}

read_values() {
  char buffer[4096];
  int read_bytes = read(main_fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  if (read_bytes == -1) { return 1; }

  struct read_format* rf = (struct read_format*) buffer;
  int values[rf->nr];
  for (int i=0; i<rf->nr; i++) {
    values[i] = rf->values[i].value;
  }
}
```

Changing `read_values()` read() call to `mmap(NULL,  sizeof(read_format), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, main_fd, 0)` didn't work. In reading the buffer back after my mmap call, the buffer is not populated as the number of events is set to 0.

```
read_values() {
  char* buffer = read(main_fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  if (buffer == MAP_FAILED) { return 1; }

  struct read_format* rf = (struct read_format*) buffer;
  if (rf->nr == 0) { return 1; }
  int values[rf->nr];
  for (int i=0; i<rf->nr; i++) {
    values[i] = rf->values[i].value;
  }
}
```

Comment: "didn't work" is not a useful problem description.  How did it fail to work? Did `mmap()` itself fail? What were the error message(s)?  Were the values unreadable even though `mmap()` appeared to work?

Comment: Aside `sizeof(read_format)` is not C code but C++. In C it would need to be `sizeof(struct read_format)`.

Comment: `mmap()` can generally only be used for real files. You can't usually map a device like a performance interface.

Comment: True, @Barmar, but the Linux kernel documentation page the OP linked explicitly claims that the file descriptor obtained as it describes *can* be `mmap`ped.  At least on some architectures.

Comment: See my answer: [read line by line in the most efficient way *platform specific*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33620968/5382650)

Answer (score 1):

`mmap()` is not related to `read()` in anyway.   `mmap()` allows you to map a file in memory, but the underlying software uses exactly the same mechanism to read the file from disk that `read()` actually uses (it moves the blocks to in memory blocks to allow several processes to access the same file of the disk).

The only difference (that could make `mmap()` a better approach against `read()`) is that it maps directly the kernel buffer (the file contents) into the virtual memory space of the project.  But this doesn't make it automatically far faster, as the acceses to the memory used for the map have still to be monitored by the kernel (on each access), to mark file buffers as dirty when you write in the space allocated to the buffer (and respect that you only write in the data area, and never in the housekeeping data)  When the inode is blocked by another process issuing a `read()` or `write()` access to the file, your process must be blocked too, to avoid accessing the data while the other process has the inode locked.

This means some mapping has to be done to the memory you write, so it is actually written in the kernel buffer corresponding to the file, and this must be done with a similar mechanism to the `copy_from`/`copy_to` copying done in read.  Things are optimized to do it fast, but the average gain is not the one in a memory access against a disk access.

Also the file must be possible to `mmap()` wich is not a general case, e.g. NFS files cannot be mapped (or it cannot be easily done) sockets and pipes cannot be mapped, and devices cannot be mapped (well, it depends, and some collaboration from the device driver is required to do it).  In general, files that cannot be `lseek()`d will not be possible to be mapped.

Comment: `mmap` works fine for reading files from NFS.  The problems are lack of synchronization between machines if both are writing + reading; it's not at all like if they were using MAP_SHARED to establish shared memory between processes on the same machine.  [mmap file shared via nfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10367577)  (NFS has close-to-open sync guarantees; `close` doesn't return until changes are sent to the server.)  All of that is totally unrelated to not-seekable reason, which is the one that AFAIK applies to `perf_event_open`.

Comment: Also, `mmap` for reading normal files is pretty closely related depending on how you look at it: a `read` system call will basically `memcpy` (inside the kernel) from the page-cache into your buffer.  An `mmap` system call lets you map those pagecache pages into your own address space, bypassing the copying.  At the expense of having more (soft or hard) page faults.  With sufficient fault-around or prefaulting, it can be faster especially for files whose data is already hot in pagecache.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I was not aware of this, and just guessed. (the NFS part)

Comment: the unseekable was only a hint, to guess if e.g. a tty or a pipe will be mmapped or no.

Comment: today implementations have disk blocks bigger than a virtual memory page... so pages can be directly mapped into disk blocks. But it was not the case when disk blocks wher 512byte or 1kb.

Comment: The unseekable part is indeed correct, I'm pretty sure there are no types of files that can be mmapped but which aren't seekable.  Oh, John Bollinger commented under the question indicate that the fd from `perf_event_open` *can* be mmaped, at least on some architectures.  Maybe it is seekable; I haven't used that API except via the `perf` utility.

Comment: char devices like tapes (or disks in unix) can be seeked on, but others (like a serial port) cannot.  For this there's a device virtual method mmap to cope with the problem of mmapping a stream device.

Comment: In Unix, disks are block devices, not char.  But yes, some char devices are seekable, like perhaps a Linux `/dev/fb0` framebuffer.  Or `/dev/zero` is a `char` device which you can mmap.  Are you sure non-seekable stream devices can be mmaped?  What does it even mean to mmap a serial port like `/dev/ttyS0`?  I can't see any sane behaviour, like write 4K bytes any time the kernel happens to notice the page is dirty?

Comment: *When the inode is blocked by another process issuing a read() or write() access to the file, your process must be blocked too, to avoid accessing the data while the other process has the inode locked.* - What are you talking about?  Unix/Linux dosn't work like that, read/write aren't exclusive. `write` system calls aren't atomic wrt. concurrent readers; software should use file locking if they want to avoid seeing torn data.  `write`s to a file that's `MAP_SHARED`  just copy into the page that your process has mapped.  And similarly, `read` just copies whatever the copy loop sees at the time.

Comment: @PeterCordes `read()` and `write()` are [supposed to be atomic](pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_07) but only WRT *each other*.  `mmap()` is not included in that, though.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Interesting, that's stronger wording than I was expecting.  I'd thought there'd only be a guarantee for atomicity in updating the file position when multiple threads make write calls on the same open file descriptor.  (And write on O_APPEND fds from separate processes is also safe because of write_pos = atomic_fetch_add(file_length, size).)  But POSIX's phrasing does seem to imply something about file data for concurrent overlapping writes (and reads) even from threads of separate processes(?) using separate FDs.  I wonder if Linux actually locks pagecache pages to do that?

Comment: @PeterCordes Given the constraints from POSIX, I'd think it would be sufficient to just lock the file's inode for the operations listed.  That would mean `mmap()`-based access to a file's data would not necessarily appear atomic.  I don't know offhand how Linux or other OSes (AIX, Solaris, BSD, HPUX *et al*) handle it, but it's possible they could lock cached pages, although I suspect most if not all don't as there's no way to lock accesses to the file's data through the `mmap()` pages.  `mmap()` access seems inherently racy for a file undergoing modification.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Oh yeah I guess you could lock the whole inode if you don't mind serializing writes to non-overlapping parts of a large existing file (that's not growing or even getting less sparse).   Presumably use-cases like databases could use `mmap` to work around that serialization, but I thought some used `write` or `pwrite` on `O_DIRECT` fds and did their own buffering in user-space.  If I get curious enough, maybe I'll write a test that does 4k-aligned `pwrite` and `pread` system calls with `memset(buf, unique_id, 4K)` unique byte values for each writer, and looks for tearing.